# How to check if a user is in an array

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to check if a joined users name is in an array, if not; ban them. If so, add role.

I've tried the code shown below, but it isn't working correctly. It's strange:

```py
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '-')

helpers = ['Mashhhyyy#7521', 'Example#1234']

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if member in helpers:
        await bot.add_roles(member, discord.Object(id='573334265690062869'))
    else:
        await bot.ban(member)
```

I expected it to check if the joined member is in the array, then if so; add the role, if not; ban. However at the current point, it is banning regardless of them being in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the string representation of the users in your code, so you have to compare them to the string representations of the object, not the `Member` object itself:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    if str(member) in helpers:
        await bot.add_roles(member, discord.Object(id='573334265690062869'))
    else:
        await bot.ban(member)
```